# I have a string representation of a byte array, but I need the original byte representation

Tags: python, encoding, python-imaging-library

I've done something that is probably fairly typical, but after a decent amount of searching, I still don't understand my problem.

I have a string that begins

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x
```

Now this is not a bytes object, this is a string, that happened to be saved with pandas.to_csv() as containing the original `b'`. I'm trying to turn this into the PNG object that it actually is, and for that I need to turn the string into a byte object in order to feed into PIL.

If I try:

```
image_data.encode()
```

I do get a bytes object, but now it looks like this:

```
b'b\'\\x89PNG\\r\\n\\x1a\\n\\x00\\x00\\
```

This has obviously been encoding incorrectly, and PIL throws: `UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f38366910a0>`

So what is the definitive solution to the problem?

Comment: It is not a string. You have the 8-bytes signature of PNG, which partly mimic ASCII. You may decode it (so `decode()` is the function, not `encode()`, but `\x89` is a binary number, and I think it has not a significance in any encodings.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi type(image_data) returns str...

Comment: See the file format, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header They choose partly string for first bytes (and no control characters), so that common errors (view image as text) are not too bad [the image format was defined before browsers supported it]. But there is no meaning of first byte. In any case, you must know the encoding of the string (PNG format was not created in your computer, with your OS, and your CPU type). And the prefix `b` means it is not a string. You may use `.decode('latin1')` (but x89 is not defined in latin1, maybe add `, errors='ignore'`)

Comment: .decode returns a string, doesn't it? But I want a bytes object... Just making sure I'm following

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. You have a binary array (`bytes` type), and so you have the original binary representation. `png[10]` gives you a numeric values. When you print, python use the *string* representation because it is more compact (and because transition from python2, where byte stringrs were also strings). If you want to print in other form, just convert every item as hex hex space, or any other representation

Comment: At some point, my bytes data was saved as a string (I think this happened because of pandas' to_csv() method, but that's probably irrelevant). So now, I have a `string` that contains the prefix `b'` indicating that it used to be a `bytes` object. I am basically looking for an easy way of recovering that hex data to convert back into the original bytes payload.

Comment: prefix `b` is not a string, it is the original bytes (bytearray): non-converted binaries. Do not be fooled by the python representation of bytearrays: Python will show ASCII codes as text, and the rest as escaped characters, when (and only when) printing. [it is handy for many encoded strings, and for quick conversion from python 2, and in any case it would be difficult to have a good string representation of binary arrays]. Again: prefix `b` is for binary data.

Comment: I understand that `b` indicates binary data. python has interpreted it as a `string` though. I don't know how else I can emphasize this... For example,  image_data[0] returns `b`.

Comment: I do not understand where python interpreted the data as string. Just to be sure: are we discussing about Python 3? One of the bad problems converting programs to python3 was about binary and string being two different types that do not mix. Which version of PIL do you use? (PIL is obsolete and not maintained, possibly you are using pillow (the continuation project). You may need to `print(type(xxx))`, to check which functions has transformed binary data into a string.

Comment: Please see my first comment. Also as mentioned, it was pandas’ to_csv() method that was responsible for the bytes -> str conversion.

Comment: Ok (I was thinking it was just an error). So you save a picture in a dataframe, and then you save that dataframe as csv, right? So the problem is in such crazy idea (you lost the advantages of dataframe, but also of CSV files [do not ever think they could be portable, with such data]). You should reframe your problem. The most common method (also on databases) it is to store filename, and have a portable file structure [maybe in a separate fileserver, possibly using hashes in directories and filenames]

Comment: That’s the solution I’ve arrived on as well. Too bad data frames aren’t more robust.

Comment: Images are outside scope of dataframes. But also for databases: it is better not to include images into data. Both are designed to store huge amount of records (and dataframe to store data in memory).

Comment: `"b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00'".replace('\\\\','\\').strip('b').strip("'").encode()` could work?